# Animate from current value with Polymer core-animation

Tags: javascript, html, animation, polymer, velocity.js

My Polymer application animates an object's `top` from an arbitrary position to `0`.  It's using Velocity to do that right now, since the way to animate from any current state to a new state is very obvious.  Is it possible (or even proper) to do with Polymer's `core-animation`?  All of the demos show fixed values at each keyframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I know of is to use the core-animation's customEffect callback.

This example animates the button when clicked:

```html
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-animation/core-animation.html">

<polymer-element name="test-element">


  <template>

    <core-animation id="animation" duration="1000" easing="ease-in-out" fill="forwards"></core-animation>

    <div relative>

      <button on-tap="{{go}}" style="position: absolute;">Click me</button>

    </div>

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({

      go: function(e, detail, sender) {

        var maxTop = 100;

        // animation target
        this.$.animation.target = sender;

        // custom animation callback
        this.$.animation.customEffect = function(timeFraction, target, animation) {
          target.style.top = (maxTop * timeFraction) + "px";
        };

        // being the animation
        this.$.animation.play();

      }


    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>



<test-element></test-element>
```

Comment: Okay, that will do.  And I see easing still works, that's cool.